# Splitting longer equation to multiple lines having various types of brackets

Tags: equations, split

I have tried to type the following equation which is long and has many brackets (types and numbers).

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tau_{\xi\eta} & = \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{\left(1-\lambda\right)\,\sigma_{0}\,e^{2\xi_{o}}}{\left(\,cosh\,2\xi - \,cos\,2\eta \right)^2} \left\lbrace \left(cosh\,2\xi - cos\,2\eta\right)\left[ sinh\,2\,(\xi-\xi_{o}) \right. \\ &\quad \left. \times sin\,2(\eta-\beta) - sinh\,2\xi_{o}\,sin\,2\beta \right] - \left[sin\,2\beta\,sinh\,2\xi (cos\,2\eta \right. \\
&\quad \left. - cosh\,2\xi_{o}) + cos\,2\beta\,sin\,2\eta(cosh\,2\xi_{o}-cosh\,2\xi)\right] \right\rbrace \\ 
&\quad - \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{\left(1+\lambda\right)\,\sigma_{0}}{\left(\,cosh\,2\xi - \,cos\,2\eta \right)^2}\times sin\,2\eta (cosh\,2\xi_{o}-cosh\,2\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

It is resulting in the following equation with errors.

[image]

I greatly appreciate insight into where things are going wrong.

Comment: It is good practice to space commands on both sides. Use `\left( \eta \right) \,` and not `\left(\eta\right)\,`, e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually all of the `\left` and `\right` directives in your code do absolutely nothing useful; in fact, their multitudinous presence makes it quite difficult to figure out which ones actually do something useful -- and replace only the useful ones with `\Bigl`, `\bigl`, `\bigr`, and `\Bigr`, respectively.

Also, do please write `\sin`, `\sinh`, `\cos`, and `\cosh`, i.e., do please use the blackslash characters. Not only will this make for better-looking output, it also lets you get rid of all 20+ [!] `\,` (thinspace) directives.

Finally, I'd place the four `&` alignment specifiers so that the `\frac{1}{2}` directives in rows 1 and 4 are aligned vertically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tau_{\xi\eta} 
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1-\lambda)\sigma_{0} e^{2\xi_{0}}}{(\cosh 2\xi - \cos 2\eta )^2} 
  \Big\lbrace (\cosh2\xi - \cos2\eta) \bigl[ \sinh2(\xi-\xi_{o})  \\ 
&\qquad  \times \sin 2(\eta-\beta) - \sinh2\xi_{o}\sin 2\beta \bigr] 
   - \bigl[\sin 2\beta\sinh2\xi (\cos2\eta  \\
&\qquad  - \cosh2\xi_{o}) + \cos2\beta\sin 2\eta(\cosh2\xi_{o}
   - \cosh2\xi)\bigr] \smash{\Big\rbrace} \\ % '\smash' is optional
&-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1+\lambda)\sigma_{0}}{(\cosh 2\xi - \cos 2\eta )^2} 
  \sin 2\eta (\cosh2\xi_{o}-\cosh2\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful inputs. I created 2 other longer equations like the one I shared here. I will now modify those as well following your suggestions. Thank you.